# Zeckendorf representation

Tags: summation, number-theory

> **Zeckendorf's theorem.**  *Every positive integer* $n$  *can be expressed uniquely as a sum of distinct non-consecutive Fibonacci numbers*
>
> *Sequence of Fibonacci numbers which add up to* $n$ *is called the [Zeckendorf representation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZeckendorfRepresentation.html) of* $n$.

I tried to define Zeckendorf's representation:

```
k=15;

sub = Subsets[Fibonacci[Range[k]]];

zeckendorf[n_] :=sub[[Flatten[Position[+## & @@@ (#) &@sub, n]]]][[1]]
```

It works perfectly

```
zeckendorf[100]
```

> $\{3, 8, 89\}$

But how can I choose  $k$, for all $n$?

I want to define it as

`Max[Fibonacci[Range[k]]]` equals  `n`. (for the given $n$)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a greedy algorithm, using results from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/67714):

```
SetAttributes[{nf, zeckendorf}, Listable];
nf[f_] := Fibonacci[Floor[(Log[f + 1/2] + Log[5]/2)/Log[GoldenRatio]]];
zeckendorf[n_Integer?Positive] := -Differences[NestWhileList[# - nf[#] &, n, # != 0 &]]
```

For example,

```
zeckendorf[Range[91, 100]]
   {{89, 2}, {89, 3}, {89, 3, 1}, {89, 5}, {89, 5, 1}, {89, 5, 2}, {89, 8}, {89, 8, 1},
    {89, 8, 2}, {89, 8, 3}}
```